# In c#, why is local variable of value type shared by different threads

Tags: c#, stack

I understand that the value type is stored in the stack area memory, except for some situations, such as the value type included as a reference type field member.

And I know that threads have different unique stack areas.

However, code execution results show that the a, b, and c threads share the count variable and increase the value to 300.

What's wrong?

```
                public void Test()
        {
            int count = 0;
            Thread a = new Thread(delegate ()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Thread ID : {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, Count : {++count}");
                }
            });
            a.Start();

            Thread b = new Thread(delegate ()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Thread ID : {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, Count : {++count}");
                }
            });
            b.Start();

            Thread c = new Thread(delegate ()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Thread ID : {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, Count : {++count}");
                }
            });
            c.Start();
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smFER.png)

Comment: There is nothing wrong why do you think behavior should be different? If you come from you mental model where the integer lives then don't do that. Its an implementation detail that might change or has changed. Go by the documented behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand that the value type is stored in the stack area memory, except for some situations, such as the value type included as a reference type field member.

In this case, `count` is a captured variable, which the compiler implements precisely by *making it* a field on an object on the heap. You can see this by compiling and decompiling the code, [like this](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) - in particular:

```cs
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
    {
        public int count;
```

This is *how the compiler achieves the required semantic* of the value being shared between all delegate usages - which in this case happens to mean "between threads" (although that isn't a necessary part).